# batch: read env var from file and asign the value prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I have a file with a list of variables.
I need to grab those variables and ask the user what value they want to assign to each one.
And so set those environment variables with that value typed in by the user.
I have this.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set "TEMP="

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    rem if "!TEMP!"=="" (SET TEMP=%%a) ELSE (SET TEMP=!TEMP!;%%a)
    SET TEMP=%%a
    echo Type %%b :
    set /p "PASS=>"%%b
    echo !TEMP!=!PASS! >> .mpo.txt
    SET /A "TEMP=!PASS!"
)
```

the file look like this:

```
VAR1
VAR2
VAR3
```

the user type: **value1**, **value2**, **value3**
And with the result to set it as envvar should look like this:

```
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
VAR3=value3
```

of course it doesn't work.
any help?

---

I add an extra for to read from the file: **.mpo.txt**

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%f in (.mpo.txt) do (
    setlocal
    SET /A "%%f=%%g"
)
```

the idea is to set line by line of this file as a envvars

in the **for** before I do this:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    rem if "!TEMP!"=="" (SET TEMP=%%a) ELSE (SET TEMP=!TEMP!;%%a)
    SET TEMP=%%a
    echo Type %%b :
    set /p "PASS=>"%%b
    echo !TEMP!=!PASS! >> .mpo.txt
)
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%f in (.mpo.txt) do (
        setlocal
        SET /A "%%f=%%g"  rem ANY HELP HERE
    )
```

Tha way I have inside the file the result that iam looking for.

```
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
VAR3=value3
```

But how to set it as env var?

Comment: I would advise from the outset, that you do not overwrite built-in environment variables. Please choose something other than `%TEMP%`.

Comment: that's true... Any help with the result that iam looking for?

Comment: `set /a` is _only_ for math. Get rid of the `/A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the exact anwser for what I was looking for was this one:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (file.txt) do (SET /P %%a="%%b: ")
```

That way I Set as envvar the variable from the text and the value what the user type as input.